# Allow Node.js app to bypass Google Firestore Authentication Rules

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I just set the rules of my Firestore project to only allow authenticated users to read/write to my database for added security. However, I also have an exterior Node.js webscraping script that runs in the background and needs to read/write to my Firestore database. There is no authentication involved, meaning it no longer has access to my database. Is there a way to allow the Node.js script to bypass the Firestore rules?

My rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Firestore Admin SDK for Node.js](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#node.js) to do your reads and writes. Security rules [do not affect calls made by the Admin SDK's](https://firebase.blog/posts/2019/03/firebase-security-rules-admin-sdk-tips).

It is important that this webscraping script is not user-controllable. Make sure to deploy it in an environment where only you, and not your app's users, have access.

Comment: Thank you, I’ll look into the Admin SDK. Also the script is running on a VM in Google Compute Engine.